# DotNetNuke installation on a shared hosting with control panel set to /admin

Tags: dotnetnuke, shared-hosting

I need to deploy DNN 5.X site on a shared hosting server. This shared hosting has its control panel set to the virtual directory /admin.
So if my site's URL is www.something.com, then the control panel will be www.something.com/admin.

The problem I am having now is that DNN has its own /admin folder with lots of controls located there. As a result, DNN fails whenever it tries to locate any control that is under the /admin path as IIS is directing that call to the Control panel Virtual directory where of course the DNN controls do not exist.

What can I do to get around this problem? What options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it an option to jump ship with this hosting provider? If you're running in to these kinds of issues on day one, imagine what the next year is going to be like.

I'd recommend avoiding the trouble by switching to a hosting provider who won't get in your way.